# Search WP API using the post title

Tags: rest-api

I'm using the WP REST API v2 to try and search for all posts with the same title, what I'm trying to do is create a sort of head-to-head/previous meetings page for 2 teams.

At the moment i can retrieve a single post with a slug no problem

```
.../wp-json/sportspress/v2/events?slug=team1-vs-team2
```

When i use a search it retrieves all the events with team1 and team2, but also all references to team1 & 2 from post content which is not what I want...

```
.../wp-json/sportspress/v2/events?search=team1+team2
```

How do i retrieve a post using the search using the exact post title as shown below in title > rendered ??

```
0   
  id    60455
  date  "2016-11-22T19:30:00"
  date_gmt  "2016-11-22T19:30:00"
  modified  "2016-11-23T09:25:29"
  modified_gmt  "2016-11-23T07:25:29"
  slug  "team1-vs-team2"
  status    "publish"
  type  "sp_event"
  link  ".../event/team1-vs-team2/"
  title 
      rendered  "Team1 vs Team2"
```

Comment: Any update to this?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's possible! You'll just need to add in a custom endpoint for the REST API.

To do that, drop the code below into your functions.php (or better yet, a plugin so it's not tied to your theme).

First, register the custom route and allow it to take a "title" parameter.

```
/**
 * Register the custom route
 *
 */
function custom_register_your_post_route() {
    register_rest_route( 'custom-search/v1', '/posts/(?P<title>.+)', array(
        array(
            'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback' => 'custom_get_post_sample'
        )
    ) );
} 
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'custom_register_your_post_route' );
```

Next, add in the custom callback function to find and return the posts you're looking for, using the built-in WP_REST_Posts_Controller.

```
/**
 * Grab all posts with a specific title
 *
 * @param WP_REST_Request $request Current request
 */
function custom_get_post_sample( $request ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // params
    $post_title = $request->get_param( 'title' );
    $post_type = 'post';

    // get all of the post ids with a title that matches our parameter
    $id_results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type= %s", urldecode( $post_title ), $post_type ) );
    if ( empty( $id_results ) ) {
        return rest_ensure_response( $request );
    }
    
    // format the ids into an array
    $post_ids = [];
    foreach( $id_results as $id ) {
        $post_ids[] = $id->ID;
    }

    // grab all of the post objects
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post__in' => $post_ids
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
 
    // prepare the API response
    $data = array(); 
    $rest_posts_controller = new WP_REST_Posts_Controller( $post_type );
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {       
        $response = $rest_posts_controller->prepare_item_for_response( $post, $request );
        $data[] = $rest_posts_controller->prepare_response_for_collection( $response );
    }
 
    // Return all of our post response data
    return rest_ensure_response( $data );
}
```

This will give you a response that looks just like the built-in Posts endpoint, including any additional data added by plugins (Yoast SEO for example).

There's plenty of additional documentation under the [Extending the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/) section at wordpress.org if you need more functionality.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works as expected. The interesting part here, which I didn't know, is that you can register api calls within my plugin...Which is a bit unsecure imho but anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible, but you can use slug instead.

Like this:

```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?slug=table
```

Reference document URL are: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#arguments

Comment: It must be possible to add post title as a searchable field using a filter?

Comment: No, as per our knowledge it's not possible. for the post title, you have to create a custom search. but you can search from post slug. Note: most of case post slug and title both are same, so if you have only post title and you want to search with the post title, you can replace title space to - and convert title to lower case it's will same as post slug(most of case)

Comment: Example: $title = 'Terms and Conditions';
$delimiter = '-'

$slug = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', $delimiter, preg_replace('/[&]/', 'and', preg_replace('/[\']/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $title))))), $delimiter));

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this through wp json, please copy the following code in the functions.php:

```
function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( empty( $search ) )
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query

    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;    
    $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

    $search =
    $searchand = '';

    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}')";
        $searchand = ' AND ';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }

    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 500, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_website_datas(){
    wp_enqueue_style(YOUR CSS link -- you must know this)
    wp_enqueue_script('my-theme-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), NULL, 'v1' , TRUE  );
    wp_localize_script('my-theme-js', 'websiteData', array(
       'root_url'  => get_site_url(),
        'nonce' =>  wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')   
    
       ))
     }
       add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_website_datas');
```

create new API route

```
     add_action('rest_api_init', 'my_new_search_api');
     function my_new_search_api(){

       //3 args - the 1st and 2nd is the API route you will hook
       // like search_route/v1/search?term=  in your getJson
       register_rest_route('search_route/v1','search', array(
        'methods'       => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
        'callback'      => 'customSearchResults'  // this is your below function

      ));
     }
```

Create the callback function

```
      function customSearchResults( $data ) {

        /* Create you  new Query */
            $mainQuery = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type'     => array('post','page','post_type1'),
                's'             => sanitize_text_field( $data['term'])  // v1/search?term 
            ));

        // create your array to append if the user attempt to search for kind of taxonomy
        $results = array( 
                'generalInfo'       => array(),
                'post_type1'        => array()
            );

        while($mainQuery->have_posts()){
            $mainQuery->the_post();

        //here when the taxonomy matches it will append the data the in array above
            if( get_post_type() == 'posts' OR get_post_type() == 'page'){
                    array_push($results['generalInfo'], array(
                        'title'         => get_the_title(),
                        'permalink'     => get_the_permalink(),
                        'postType'      => get_post_type(),
                        'authorName'    => get_the_author()
                    ));
        
            } 
        
            if( get_post_type() == 'post_type1'){
        
                    array_push($results['post_type1'], array(
                        'title'     => get_the_title(),
                        'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                        'postType'  => get_post_type(),
                        'authorName'    => get_the_author()
                    ));
        
                } 
    
      return $results;
    }
}
```

Next in your JS file
The code is too long you must guess this this.searchField.val() part haha

```
 $.getJSON(websiteData.root_url + '/wp-json/university/v1/search?term=' + 
   this.searchField.val(), (results) => {
   
  // now you can append the result to wherever element you want.      
   this.resultsDiv.html(`
     <p> ${results} </p> `)

   }
```

This code will work if you know what you are doing.
Hope this helps!